# Angular: controller's methods are not working in directive's template

Tags: angularjs

Here is a directive that is loading new Template from file:

```
.directive('candidatesFilter', function(){
    return {
        resctict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/directives/filters/AAAA.html' 
    }
})
```

Next HTML-element calls this directive from the other HTML-Template (e.g. xxx.html):

```
<candidates-filter></candidates-filter>
```

There is next controller for this parent Template (xxx.html):

```
app.controller('candidatesController', function($scope, $location ){

    $scope.addPeson = function() {
        $location.url('/candidate/0');
    };

});
```

Method addPerson() is not accessible inside the Directive's template **AAAA.html**, because

```
data-ng-click="addPerson()"
```

is not working there. How to change the Directive to make addPerson() method available inside the directive's template?

**TEMPORARY Solution**
I fixed this issue by next solution

```
.directive('candidatesFilter', function(){
    return {
        resctict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/directives/filters/AAAA.html', 
        controller: function(){
            $('button.add').on('click',function(){
                location.hash = '#/candidate/0';
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly:

You can pass a function into the directive for it to use

`<candidates-filter></candidates-filter>`

becomes

`<candidates-filter add-candidate="addPerson()"></candidates-filter>`

and the directive definition changed as follows:

```
.directive('candidatesFilter', function() {
return {
    resctict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        addCandidate: '&addCandidate'
    }
    templateUrl: 'views/directives/filters/AAAA.html'
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.someFunctionInDirective = function() {
            scope.addCandidate();
        }
    };
}
})
```

Alternatively you can call it with the ng-click like normal from the button

Hope this helps clarify it?

Comment: Could do with a bigger set of information from you so I can see how it's wired up, use the console and do `console.log("Hello test")` in places to see if it gets called?

Comment: I fixed the issue in another way. In Directive description i added:

controller: function(){
    $('button.add').on('click',function(){
        location.hash = '#/candidate/0';
    });
}